# how to print Test-page on default Printer?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to print Test-page on default Printer

using C# Winform Code ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Click the 'Print test page' button in the printer driver dialog.  Why on Earth would you want to write C# code to do that?

Comment: @HansPassant because if you want to manager the printer on your own and want to give the user the possibility to test them directly.

Answer (score 2):

To generate the built-in Windows test page, you can also use p/invoke against PrintUI.dll.  Here's a simple class which lets you do this:

```
public static class PrintTestPageHelper
{
    [DllImport("printui.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern void PrintUIEntryW(IntPtr hwnd, 
        IntPtr hinst, string lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

    /// <summary>
    /// Print a Windows test page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="printerName">
    /// Format: \\Server\printer name, for example:
    /// \\myserver\sap3
    /// </param>
    public static void Print(string printerName)
    {
        var printParams = string.Format(@"/k /n{0}", printerName);
        PrintUIEntryW(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, printParams, 0);
    }
}

public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintTestPageHelper.Print(@"\\printserver.code4life.com\sap3");

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI, specifically, the [PrintTestPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392757%28VS.85%29.aspx) method of the [Win32_Printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28VS.85%29.aspx) class.

See this MSDN article for how to execute a WMI method from C#: [How To: Execute a Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257364%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As ho1 said the WMI can accommodate you:

```
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Printer");
ManagementBaseObject outP = processClass.InvokeMethod("PrintTestPage", null);
if (Convert.ToUInt32(outP["ReturnValue"]) != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to print test page.");
}
```

Whenever you call print on a PrintDocument without specifying a printer it will of course use the default:

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
doc.Print(); // will print a blank page
```